# Reduzir imagem junto com a div

Tags: javascript, css, css-transições, transição

Olá! Eu estou editando um Front do Site da empresa em que trabalho e atualmente estou na parte do menu de navegação. Toda vez que rolo a página para baixo ele "encolhe" porém a Logo da Empresa continua do mesmo tamanho, ela não reduz junto com a Div.

O que eu preciso é de algum CSS ou Javascript para que quando a div encolher, a imagem reduza junto, de preferência com algum efeito de easing pra não ficar tão "seco". Se não houver como reduzir ela, pode ser um CSS/Javascript para alterar a imagem, então eu coloco uma menor, de preferência também com um efeito de easing. Exemplos:

Quando abre a página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando rola paga baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se ajuda em algo mas percebi que é inserida uma classe no menu de navegação quando ocorre essa transição do "recolhimento".

Código normal:

```
<nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="./front/images/logo1.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
```

Quando recolhido, o nav muda e fica assim (é adicionado um **top-nav-collapse**):

```
<nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top top-nav-collapse" role="banner">
```

---

**RESOLVIDO**

Apenas adicionei ao CSS:

```
.top-nav-collapse img {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: padding 300ms ease;
}
```

Com as dicas de vocês eu consegui resolver, muito obrigado!

Comment: Se quando faz o scroll é adicionado o ` top-nav-collapse` na imagem no seu css coloque `. top-nav-collapse { height: 30px; width:auto}` ou o height que quiser. Se funcionar fala ai

Comment: Valeu @CaetanoSincero funcionou em parte, mas consegui resolver usando as dicas de todos aqui!

Answer (score 1):

Cara, como está usando o bootstrap, só usar a `class: img-fluid` na sua tag `img`. Ficaria assim:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img class="img-fluid" src="./front/images/logo1.png" alt="logo"></a>
```

Você pode acessar esse link para ver mais sobre imagens no Bootstrap:

https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/content/images/

Comment: Tentei com este código e não mudou nada :/

Comment: Cara, há algo de errado então na configuração do CSS de sua nav, pois essa classe faz com que a imagem se adapte conforme vai diminuindo a tela, ou seja, do mesmo jeito que a NAV ia diminuir, a imagem também iria.

Answer (score 0):

Ola tenta mudar a tua class de `navbar-fixed-top` para `sticky-top`

E podes tambem usar a propriedade scroll-smooth de css para ajudar no teu efeito

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Podes tambem criar um class em css para a tua nav que vai criar uma transição mais lenta

```
nav{
 transition: padding 300ms ease;
}
```

Quanto ao JS podes usar um event listener na janela que vai chamar uma função quando tens um scroll

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){

  // posição de scroll
  var scrollPosition = Math.round(window.scrollY);

  // Verifica se 100px, e adiciona a class sticky a tua nav
 if (scrollPosition > 100){
      document.querySelector('nav').classList.remove('navbar-fixed-top');
      document.querySelector('nav').classList.add('sticky-top');
 }
 else {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.remove('sticky-top');
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.add('navbar-fixed-top');
 }
});
```

Para mais informações podes usar a doc do bootstrap aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, o navbar agora fixou solto e quando rolo a página pra baixo ele some. Tem que manter fixado mesmo.

Comment: Minhas desculpas, `<nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default sticky-top" role="banner">` tente com o seguinte

Comment: Com o segundo código ainda tem o mesmo efeito.

Comment: Cara achei que ele queria era diminuir a altura da imagem dentro do menu, não trocar fixed por sticky

Comment: Do que entendi ele quer ter um menu em cima da pagina sempre e que o tamanho deste menu que contem a imagem se torne mais pequeno quando faz scroll